# Posting from the frontend mostly working

Tags: wordpress, post, frontend

I'm using this front end code to create a post. At the moment it does create a post but the only thing that works is the title.

I also have a custom metabox with some fields (more_info, priority and duedate and ) in my post as well but I'm not sure if I'm putting them in the array correctly. Note that in the backend those additional fields work just fine.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter a title';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
}

// Add the content of the form to $post as an array
$post = array(
    'post_title'      => $title,
    'post_content'  => $description,
    'more_info'    => $more_info,
    'priority'      => $priority,
    'duedate'       => $duedate,
    'post_category'   => $_POST['cat'],
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'    => $_POST['post']
);
wp_insert_post($post);
}
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 

?>

<form action="" id="new_post" method="post">
<label for="title">Task Name </label>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" />

<label for="minfo">Additional information</label>
<textarea name="minfo" id="minfo" value=""></textarea>

<label>Due date</label>
<input type="text" id="duedate" name="duedate" />


    <strong>Priority</strong>
    <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="low" id="low">Low</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="normal" id="normal" checked>Normal</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="high" id="high">High</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="urgent" id="urgent">Urgent</label>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />

<input type="hidden" name="cat" id="cat" value="<?php echo $cat_id = get_query_var('cat'); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

</form>
```

Any assistance would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, couple things:

1. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Do you need users to have the ability to add the values submitted in this meta box to any post? If not, why not create a custom post type that you can tweak to your heart's content?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, then you're still going to want to attach your save methods differently. Something like:

   ```
   add_meta_box(
       'my-custom-meta', // Unique ID
       esc_html__('Custom Attributes', 'my_scope'), // Title
       'my_custom_meta_box', // Callback function
       'post', // Admin page (or post type)
       'normal', // Context
       'high' // Priority
   );


   function my_custom_meta_box( $object ) { ?>

       <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_custom_inner', 'my_custom_inner_nonce' ); ?>

       <p>
           <label for="minfo">Additional information</label>
           <textarea name="minfo" id="minfo" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'minfo', true ) ); ?>"></textarea>
       </p>
       <p>
           <label>Due date</label>
           <input type="text" id="duedate" name="duedate" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'duedate', true ) ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>
           <strong>Priority</strong>
           <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="low" id="low"<?php if ( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'priority', true ) == 'low' ) { echo ' checked'; }?>>Low</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="normal" id="normal"<?php if ( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'priority', true ) == 'normal' ) { echo ' checked'; }?>>Normal</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="high" id="high"<?php if ( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'priority', true ) == 'high' ) { echo ' checked'; }?>>High</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="priority" value="urgent" id="urgent"<?php if ( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'priority', true ) == 'urgent' ) { echo ' checked'; }?>>Urgent</label>
       </p>

   <?php }


   function save_my_meta( $post_id ) {
       // Check if our nonce is set.
       if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_custom_inner_nonce'] ) )
           return $post_id;

       $nonce = $_POST['my_custom_inner_nonce'];

       // Verify that the nonce is valid.
       if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my_custom_inner' ) )
           return $post_id;

       // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
       if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
           return $post_id;

       // Check the user's permissions.
       if ( $_REQUEST['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
           if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
               return $post_id;
       }

       /* Cast the returned vaiables to an array for processing */
       $my_meta['minfo'] = $_REQUEST['minfo'];
       $my_meta['duedate'] = $_REQUEST['duedate'];
       $my_meta['priority'] = $_REQUEST['priority'];

       foreach ( $my_meta as $key => $value ) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
           if(get_post_meta( $post_id, $key ) ) { // If the custom field already has a value
               update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, sanitize_text_field( $value ) );
           } else {
               add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, sanitize_text_field ( $value ) );
           }
           if( !$value ) delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key ); // Delete if blank
       }
   }
   add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_meta' );
   ```

Comment: I already have a custom metabox for 'posts' which works fine in the backend (looks like this i.imgur.com/URRFHpO.png). It's just trying to create the post from the front end (from a form in one of my templates) as well.